# Access VBA throwing unlisted error code

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm seeing an error code like this in my Access 2000 VBA:

> -2147352567-Record in '[SomeTable]' was deleted by another user.

So, 2 questions:

1) How do I handle/avoid an error code like this?

2) Can anyone explain why I'm getting an error code that doesn't seem to exist in MS documentation?  And is there some way to decipher this code?  Is it a combination of several codes?  Any guidance on this topic would be appreciated.

```
Public Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)

' Check for unposted record / regardless of Date / Shift
' If there is an unposeted record goto it

  Dim lCheck
  Dim sPress As String

On Error GoTo Form_Open_Err

GotoRecord:

  If bPressConsumptionOpenRan = True Then
    lCheck = DLookup("PressConsumptionID", "spI_GetUnPostedRecord")
    If Not IsNothing(lCheck) Then
      Me.txtPressConsumptionID.SetFocus
      DoCmd.FindRecord lCheck
    Else
      DoCmd.SetWarnings False
      DoCmd.OpenQuery ("spI_InsertNewPressConsumption")
      Me.Requery
      DoCmd.SetWarnings True
    End If
  End If

Form_Open_Exit:

  Exit Sub

Form_Open_Err:

  sErrMsg = Err.Number & "-" & Err.Description
  MsgBox sErrMsg, vbCritical + vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Program Error"
```

So I just commented out the

> On Error GoTo

lines in Form_Open(), Form_Load(), and Form_Activate(), and still no debugger call.  This error is shown when the db is opened, so I have no idea where else the error could be in the code.

And here is the code for IsNothing:

```
Public Function IsNothing(vCheck As Variant) As Boolean

On Error GoTo IsNothing_Err

  If IsNull(vCheck) Then IsNothing = True: Exit Function
  If IsEmpty(vCheck) Then IsNothing = True: Exit Function
  If Trim(vCheck) = "" Then IsNothing = True: Exit Function

IsNothing_Err:

  IsNothing = False

End Function
```

Now I'm getting a similar error in Form_Current():

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

  Dim sUser As String

On Error GoTo Form_Current_Err

  If IsNothing(Me.dtpUsageDate) Then
    Me.dtpUsageDate = Date   'This line throws error.
  End If

...Ommitted to save space.  Not relevant...

Form_Current_Err:

  sErrMsg = Err.Number & "-" & Err.Description
  MsgBox sErrMsg, vbCritical + vbOKOnly + vbInformation, "Program Error"
  Resume Form_Current_Log

Form_Current_Log:

  On Error Resume Next
  Call LogError(sErrMsg, "PressConsumptions_Form_Current")
  GoTo Form_Current_Exit

End Sub
```

Error Message:

> -2417352567-There is no object in this control.

Is this message related to the other one we've been seeing?  Any thoughts on correcting?

Comment: Are you using an ODBC table ( http://support.microsoft.com/kb/172339 ) ?

Comment: Yes, I am.  I'm still trying to determine why/how the record got deleted.  I have a sub which inserts a new record, I'd like to handle this error code by running that sub.

Comment: -2147352567 is the lower bound of a 32-bit Integer data type.

Comment: @Jay- Good catch!  But why would that be listed as the error code?  I wonder if it means some invalid data was entered into an int field?

Comment: Sorry, I don't really know; the number just stood out to me. Maybe a concurrency error usually shows a row number, or primary key value, but when the record has been deleted it can't. I'm just speculating.

Comment: What were you doing prior to getting this error? I wonder if BOF and EOF were true? Apparently this error can occur with an empty recordset, amongst other reasons, so a little code might be a good idea.

Comment: EOF and BOF both being true seems unlikely.  I know there was data there in the table.  BOF and EOF could only be true then if Jet didn't grab the data correctly.

Comment: I edited my comment a little too late, perhaps you could post a little code leading up to the problem?

Comment: Disable your On Error statement like this: `'On Error GoTo Form_Open_Err`  Then tell us which line throws the error.

Comment: If spI_InsertNewPressConsumption is an "action" query, execute it with `CurrentDb.Execute spI_InsertNewPressConsumption, dbFailonerror`  That way you don't need to SetWarnings off.

Comment: You should check that lCheck is null, not IsNothing. IsNothing is not a VBA function, unless you have written your own.

Comment: Is the form's data source based on some other table/query that is affected by spl_InsertNewPressConsumption? Maybe it's affecting the record you are currently on.

Comment: @Remou- IsNothing is a custom function, although written before me, so I can't vouch for its correctness.

Comment: @HansUp- Now I'm really confused.  The debugger didn't come up, but I still got the error code.  Perhaps the error is being thrown on a later line of code?   I'm looking for a likely culprit now.

Comment: What is the sequence of events?  What is the proper running order of Form_Load(), Form_Open(), Form_Activate() etc.

Comment: Errors in this range are usually thrown by the data access component you're using (DAO or ADO), not by Access. You can sometimes find a bit of explanation by searching MSDN for "Error _x_".

Comment: Do not use IsNothing, DLookUp is not returning an object, but a string or null. Just check for null. You can iterate through the errors collection to get all the errors thrown, dbFailOnError, as suggested by HansUp will help (BTW there are advantages to Set db=CurrentDB, db.Execute). DAO errors collection: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff835711.aspx

Comment: @Remou- vba is not my strong language, are you suggesting I use If lcheck <> NULL ?  What is the proper syntax for such a statement?

Comment: @Remou- Please see the IsNothing() function which I've now edited into the question.  Still concerned?

Comment: @Remou- Should I Dim the lcheck as a String?  I'm not sure what the default is if no datatype is specified (in vba).

Comment: If you Dim as string you will get an error if null is returned, variant would be better.

Comment: IsNothing looks okay, but the name is the same as a common function in VB (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5adx7fxz(v=vs.80).aspx), but not in VBA, which may lead to confusion at some stage.

Comment: Rather than turning off the error handler (by commenting out the On Error GoTo statement), just set the VBE options to BREAK ON ALL ERRORS. That way you don't have to remember to turn the error handler on again -- you'll definitely remember to turn BREAK ON ALL ERRORS off again, because it's will cause all sorts of already-handled errors to pop up.

Comment: @Remou- I imagine my predecesor missed the IsNothing() function and thus wrote one called that to simulate normal VB.

Answer (score 0):

The error number and message suggest to me that this is a problem from outside of Access. The fact that you're executing a saved query that has a name suggesting that it runs an SPROC on a database server suggests to me that the back end is SQL Server or some other back end.

It's a very common error in Access when you don't have both a primary key and a timestamp field in your back end table. It's caused by the fact that Access can't tell exactly which record is involved and can't refresh the display appropriately. Having a PK and a timestamp field usually gets rid of the problem.

But it may be caused by something else, of course.

Comment: It is a stored proc on an SQL Server database.  Unfortunately, my table has both a primary key and a timestamp.

Comment: What's the data type of your PK? Shouldn't matter, but it could. Have you confirmed if the record is actually deleted or not? If it is, you need to identify the source of the deletion and determine if it is correct or not. If it's not deleted, it's perhaps the problem that comes from setting fields to Null, which Jet/ACE uses to query the server on Field = Null, which, of course, doesn't work.